# accessing other users calendar in google apps by super admin

Tags: api, google-app-engine, gdata-api, google-apps

As we know Super administrators also have full access to all users' calendars and calendar event details.

I found these API's

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/ which can be used to retrieve calendar's related to a user.

i read google docs api

for getting information about a current user we use default
https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/...

and for getting information about other user in the same domain
https://docs.google.com/feeds/user@yourdomain.com/...

we have to replace default with user's email address.

but in calendar's api for accessing list of current user's calendar's list
we use this url
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList

if current user is an administrator and i have to retrieve list of calendar of other user in the same domain then how to retrieve that list
i tried to call https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/rashmi@riteshmehandiratta.com/calendarList
response is  Not Found.riteshmehandiratta.com is my domain and rashmi is a user so email address is rashmi@riteshmehandiratta.com i authorize my app by super administrator and successfully get access token and putting header
Authorization with OAuth anonymous_access_token so there is no problem with  authorization part of url.

can any one please help how to retrieve other user's calendar list in the same domain by super administrator via api call?plz.. plz.. help

Comment: I have the same problem with a project. Did you mange to find a solution for this?